# GetTemplateChild returns null in OnApplyTemplate

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

i created a class for my pages with extend of 'ContentControl'

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace WpfApp1
{
    public class page_controller : ContentControl
    {
        public string title { get; set; }
    }
}
```

and this is my window xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp1"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Window.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type local:page_controller}">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:page_controller}">
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=title, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ContentControl}, Mode=TwoWay}"
                                       FontSize="24"
                                       TextWrapping="Wrap"
                                       Foreground="#FFfd8900"
                                       VerticalAlignment="Top"
                                       TextAlignment="Center" />
                        </StackPanel>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>

        <local:page_controller x:Name="page_controller" title="default which i don't wan it !" />

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

here i created a style for my page controller with a text block which is going to print the 'title'

and i called that element '`page_controller`'

now in the C# of this window, i want do some checks and change the `page_controller.title` before window come up ! so i did this

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace WpfApp1
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        page_controller page;

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public override void OnApplyTemplate()
        {
            base.OnApplyTemplate();

            string new_title = ....; // do some checks to set new title

            page = GetTemplateChild("page_controller") as page_controller; // Jesus ****** Christ ! ERROR !!! (page) is null !!!!!!

            page.title = new_title ; // error (crash (null)) !!
        }
    }
}
```

i used `GetTemplateChild` in `OnApplyTemplate` to get that `page_controller` object in xaml which i called it `page_controller` but something's wrong !!! `GetTemplateChild` returns null !!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`GetTemplateChild` is only used to get an element from inside a `Control`'s `ControlTemplate`.

`page_controller` is not part of `MainWindow`'s `ControlTemplate`, it is part of its `Content`. You can reference elements defined in a `Window`'s content simply by using its `Name` as a variable name. You already have `x:Name="page_controller"`, so the variable name is `page_controller`.

Try it in the `Window.Loaded` event:

```
private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    string new_title = ....; // do some checks to set new title
    page_controller.title = new_title;
}
```

---

Seperate note: public properties and type names should be capitalized using "PascalCasing":
[MSDN - Capitalization Conventions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/capitalization-conventions)

Comment: thx but i didn't find Window_Loaded !! but i jut put the name (x:Name="page_controller") in OnApplyTemplate(), and there i changed the title and it's worked ..